# Execeute multiple commands from one string in Batch file

Tags: string, batch-file

For some reason, I need to execute a multiple commannds from one string in my Batch file. I've tried this code:

```
@echo off
set multipleCommands=echo command1 ^& echo command2 ^& echo command3
echo.
%multipleCommands%
pause
```

but it gives me this result:

```
command1 & echo command2 & echo command3
```

I also tried another code:

```
@echo off
set multipleCommands=echo command1 & echo command2 & echo command3
echo.
%multipleCommands%
pause
```

but it gives me this result (because `multipleCommands=echo command1` only):

```
command2
command3

command1
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: This works here: `set "multipleCommands=echo command1 & echo command2 & echo command3"`

Comment: Your first code cannot give the result you posted.Instead, It performs the three `echo` commands sequentially. If you want to actually execute the 3 commands and not `echo` them, then simply remove `echo` from the string definition.

Answer (score 1):

Firsly there is no reason, the `&` acts in the same manner as another command on a new line.

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo=
command1
command2
command3
Pause
```

However your issue seems to be that you're somheow transfixed with the use of echo!

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "multipleCommands=command1 & command2 & command3"
Echo=
%multipleCommands%
Pause
```

You'd need to understand that each of those commands will open once the previous one has closed too. If you wanted them to run at the same time you'd need to use:

```bat
Set "multipleCommands=start command1 & start command2 & start command3"
```